# How count value of an attribute on different json pages using php

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I'm a beginner in php

I have this problem:

I need to plus up the total value of each sale of a json, but it is divided into pages! therefore, I must add the total sale of each page

***Example:***

***- On page 1: I have 100 orders, each one costing 10 dollars, in the total of this page I will have a value of 1000.***

***- On page 2: I have 50 orders costing 10 dollars, therefore in the total of this page 500 reais***

**Now I need plus the total of these two pages**

This is the api url.

```
$url = 'https://bling.com.br/Api/v2/pedidos/page=1/' . $outputType  . '/?'  . $dataEmissao;



$return = executeGetOrder($url, $apikey);


$obj = json_decode($return);
$subItem = $obj->return->orders;

$total = 0;


for($i = 0; $i < count($subItem); $i++) {
    $total += $subItem[$i]->orders->totalSale;
}
```

Important to remember that each page only shows 100 orders, sometimes I have the first page with 100 orders and the second page with.

Function executeGetOrder

```
function executeGetOrder($url, $apikey){
$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url . '&apikey=' . $apikey);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$response = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
return $response;
```

}

Comment: you know the total number of pages?

Comment: What happens when you have 500 orders (5 pages)? Does it mean page 1 will have total sum of first 100 orders while page 2 have total sum of first 200 orders (which is page 1 & 2) ... and page 5 will have total of all 500 orders?

Comment: I do not know the total number of pages :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it, I made some changes

```
$page = 1;

$totalOrders = 0;

do {

$url = 'https://bling.com.br/Api/v2/pedidos/page=' . $page . '/' . $outputType . '/?' . $dataEmissao . '&apikey=' . $apikey;

$retorno = executeGetOrder($url);

$obj = json_decode($retorno);


if(!empty($obj->retorno->pedidos)) {


    $totalOrdersPage = count($obj->return->orders);

    $totalOrders += $totalOrdersPage;

    $page++;


    // Search each orders 
    foreach ($obj->retorno->pedidos as $pedido) {
        // Add value total sales of the orders in $grandTotal
        $grandTotal += $orders->order->totalsale;
    }

} else {
    $totalOrdersPage = 0;
}



} while ($totalOrdersPage > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the information of total number of pages you can do something like:

```
$page = 1;
$grandTotal = 0;

while ($return = executeGetOrder('https://bling.com.br/Api/v2/pedidos/page=' . $page . '/' . $outputType  . '/?'  . $dataEmissao, $apikey)) {
    $obj = json_decode($return);
    $subItem = $obj->return->orders;

    $total = 0;

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($subItem); $i++) {
        $total += $subItem[$i]->orders->totalSale;
    }

    $grandTotal += $total;
    $page ++;
}
```

And then it's important that when your `executeGetOrder` function sends an HTTP request and finds out that the page does not exist, then it will return `false` or `null`.

- Thought: you can add a condition to the loop in order to avoid unnecessary request most of the times when the last page has fewer orders than the rest. So for example, if you have 100 orders per page, you can add `&& $grandTotal % 100 == 0`

---

If you know the total number of pages, then you better do a `for` loop: (avoiding unnecessary request):

```
$totalPages = ?;
$grandTotal = 0;

for ($page = 1; $page <= $totalPages; $page ++) {
    $return = executeGetOrder('https://bling.com.br/Api/v2/pedidos/page=' . $page . '/' . $outputType  . '/?'  . $dataEmissao, $apikey)
    $obj = json_decode($return);
    $subItem = $obj->return->orders;

    $total = 0;

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($subItem); $i++) {
        $total += $subItem[$i]->orders->totalSale;
    }

    $grandTotal += $total;
}
```

---

Comment: Hi! I used the while, but there was a new problem, it was the error in the line $subItem = $obj->return->orders;           
error message: Trying to get property of non-object in

Comment: I added details of the executeGetOrder function, I believe that there is the problem when it is perfomed in the while

Comment: @GuilhermeLucas Try to use `executeGetOrder` function, and try to send a request to a valid page, and also to an invalid page. For both request do `var_dump($response);` and tell me what are the results.